# "Window error:- Unable to find specified file" in Python

Tags: java, python, qgis

I am trying to call jar file from qgis Python plugin using

```
subprocess.call(['java', '-jar', 'abc.jar', 'Path'])
```

and want to close qgis after calling jar using

```
 sys.exit(0)
```

If I  run this code from individual file it runs fine but when I run it from qgis plug-in in Windows and Centos system it is throwing error

In Windows system

```
 Window error:- Unable to find specified file
```

In Centos system

```
Error:-   Unable to access file
```

I am unable to find out the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
subprocess.call(['java', '-jar', 'abc.jar', 'Path'],shell=True)
```

Comment: thnaks  error is resoled but the jar file not run from this code

Comment: use java full path e.g. /usr/bin/java
read about path environment variable
http://www.linfo.org/path_env_var.html

Comment: I used it but Its not calling

Comment: is it possible to hide splash screen while calling jar/exe from python